# Datetimepicker: Cannot select minutes less than current minute although hour is selected to higher than current hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetime, datetimepicker

When i set minDate is "2017/05/09 10:16:00", if i use the arrow to set hour higher min hour (e.g: 11h), i can set minutes less than min minutes (e.g: 10m). But if i set hour by using select from grid table, i cant select minutes which less than min minutes. Anyone have solution for this issue? Please help me, sorry for my bad English.
[image]

my datetimepicker setting:

```
    $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm ZZ",
    locale: "ja",
    sideBySide: true,
    toolbarPlacement: "bottom",
    showClose: true,
    widgetPositioning:{
      horizontal: "auto",
      vertical: "top"
    },
    icons: {
      close: "btn-info date-time-close-text"
    }
  });
```

Views:

```
<div class="time-picker-wrapper">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :public_time, class: "form-control datepicker time-public",
      placeholder: t(".public_time"), readonly: notification.public_time.nil? && is_edit_page %>
    <%= f.text_field :created_at, class: "datepicker hidden" %>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="icon-time-picker-wrapper">
    <i class="mp-icon-time-picker"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using a lot of options in there. I pulled up an app I have with datetimepicker and it doesn't have the issue you do. What I recommend is to start with the most basic setup and start adding options until the issue starts then at least you know which option is causing it.

Comment: i'll try it, thankyou for your suggest!

Comment: I think I see an issue as well. You have two datetimepicker fields using the same JavaScript function. Try giving them different #ids and make two JavaScript functions. One for each. They may be interacting with each other giving you unexpected results.

Comment: i already remove second text_field but this problem still happen. And i also remove all options but this problem still happen in default setting. I use this datetimepicker bootstrap: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic setup that works for me without the issue you mentioned. As I said in the comment this has two time/date fields - start and end. And the minDate for the end is the start date, and max date for the start is the end date. See if this works for you. I'm leaving my field names so you can change them.

**JavaScript file:**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('#event_start').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'
  });
  $('#event_end').datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false, 
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'
  });
  $('#event_start').on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#event_end').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });
  $("#event_end").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#event_start').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
  });
});
```

**Form Fields**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :start, 'Start Date-Time', class: 'control-label' %>
  <div class='input-group date' id='event_start'>
    <%= f.text_field :start, class: "form-control" %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
  <%= f.label :end, 'End Time (Optional)', class: 'control-label' %>
  <%= f.text_field :end, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

Comment: i already remove second text_field but this problem still happen.

Comment: I used the same gem so the gem works. Maybe start with a very basic setup. I'll change my answer to the very basic one that works for me. You can start with that and see if it works.

Comment: it still happen, did you set minDate in your datetimepicker? I think this is a Datetimepicker bug.

Comment: I don't know I just checked and I am not getting the issue you mention if I understand it correctly. In my app I have fields for start date/time and end date/time and I set end date/time to minDate of the start. And I can advance the hour but go back on the minutes. I'll change my answer again to show this.

Comment: you can check my problem in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRFSg3Fc_xA&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

i have do hardwork all day and finally find a solution for my problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var default_time = null;

  $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm ZZ",
    locale: "ja",
    sideBySide: true,
    toolbarPlacement: "bottom",
    showClose: true,
    widgetPositioning:{
      horizontal: "auto",
      vertical: "top"
    },
    icons: {
      close: "btn-info date-time-close-text"
    }
  }).on("dp.show", function(){
    default_time = moment();
  });

  $(".datepicker").on("dp.change", function(){
    var time_set = $(".datepicker").val();
    var date_time_set = new Date(time_set);
    if (date_time_set.getHours() > default_time.hours()){
      $("td.minute.disabled").removeClass("disabled");
    }
    else if (date_time_set.getDate() > default_time.date()){
      $("td.minute.disabled").removeClass("disabled");
      $("td.hour.disabled").removeClass("disabled");
    }
    else if (date_time_set.getDate() == default_time.date()){
      $(".datepicker").data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment());
    }
  });
```

i hope this answer can help someone and if you have any feedback and comment about my code, just tell me. Thankyou!

Comment: Cool, glad you got it fixed.